# GCM Push Notification NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I am newbie to push notifications, and i have done the code part which i have taken reference from googling and it is working fine, but my query is :

1. sending push notification to group of people (using array)
2. and there is chance to be at least one wrong gcm-id in that array
3. if there is a wrong gcm-id, populates error like "Not Registered" or "MisplacingId" (while sending individually)
4. Now, the gcm-id is in an array, then the push will send for remaining people or it will block there itself?

and here is my code :

```
var GCM = require('gcm').GCM;
var apiKey = 'xyz';
var gcm = new GCM('apiKey');

var message = {
    registration_id: ['x','y'],
    collapse_key: 'Hello',
    priority: 'high', 
    contentAvailable: true,
    delayWhileIdle: true,
    timeToLive: 3,
};

gcm.send(message, function(err, messageId){
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something has gone wrong!");
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Sent with message ID: ", messageId);
    }
});
```

and please tell me there is any limt(Number of gcmid's)? in one push?

Answer (score 0):

It will send push notifications to all the registration ids even if few of them appear to be invalid in between the array.
Sample response when the registration id is not valid

```
{
  multicast_id: 8976424350191695000,
  success: 1,
  failure: 1,
  canonical_ids: 1,
  results: [
    {
      registration_id: "value-of-correct-registration-id",
      message_id: "0:1460568231005603%ade1213ff9fd7ecd"
    },
    {
      error: "InvalidRegistration"
    }
  ]
}
```

The success and failure count will show the number of push notifications sent and failed. And there is no limit applied on the number of registration ids.